# If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $S$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, then there’s a $g\in G$ such that $H\cap gSg^{-1}$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, sylow-theory

I’m reading a proof of the above statement and having difficulties understanding the first step. It says that the stabilizer of any element $gS\in X=G/S$ is $H\cap gSg^{-1}$. I guess I should be considering here $H$’s action on $X$ by left traslation, but I don’t see how the result is obtained.

Also, the proof seems to use this fact to conclude that $H\cap gSg^{-1}$ is a $p$-subgroup but this seems obvious to me (the conjugated subgroup of a $p$-subgroup is always a $p$-subgroup, and its intersection with another subgroup must be a $p$-subgroup too, right?).

So I don’t understand why the stabilizer was needed at all.

Comment: "To conclude that $H\cap gSg^{-1}$"... seems like there is a clause missing in that sentence. Note that you need to show that the intersection is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$, and what your argument gives is just that it is *a* $p$-subgroup.

Comment: Presumably, they use the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem for a well-chosen $g$ to show that the index of $H\cap gSg^{-1}$ in $H$ equals the length of the orbit of $gS$ under the action, and show that this length is relatively prime to $p$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, I know that my argument only gives that ir’s a $p$-subgroup! But it was just that part of the proof which I didn’t understand. (Oh sorry, I just realized I didn’t write that down on the question). You’re right, using the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem was the next step.

Comment: Right; so the fact that it is a $p$-subgroup does not use the fact that this is the result of an action, but the application of the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, which is the key part of the argument, does. Perhaps the wording wasn't entirely transparent (I would say something like "Note that $H\cap gSg^{-1}$ is a $p$-subgroup of $H$" to avoid giving the impression that this is a conclusion of the work. But I don't know what they actually say or how they say it, so it is difficult to say if your confusion is warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you a different proof: Let $P$ be a Sylow subgroup of $H$. By Sylow's theorem $P$ lies in a Sylow subgroup $Q$ of $G$ and $Q$ is conjugate to $S$. Hence, there exists $g\in G$ such that $P\le gSg^{-1}$. Now $H\cap gSg^{-1}$ is a $p$-subgroup of $H$ which cannot be bigger than the Sylow subgroup $P$. Therefore $H\cap gSg^{-1}=P$.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful for my intuition! But this result appears in my notes as a lemma that’s actually used to prove Sylow’s theorem, so I guess I should try to prove it independently. I already know a proof of Sylow’s theorem that doesn’t use this lemma, but I’m trying to understand the course material!